# Is Entity Framework Feature Community Technology Preview 4 production ready?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is [Entity Framework Feature Community Technology Preview 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e) production ready?

Where I can find the release? (if it exists)

I confused with word 'CTP'

Explain, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTP is a Community Technology Preview.  It's just meant to gain feedback from the community before releasing a beta or the final product.  The current CTP does not have a "go-live" license which means you cannot use it in production.

This does not mean that you aren't allowed to tinker with it and try it out.  You can download it from the site you linked and play with it all you want.  Just beware of the license agreement, and wait for a "go-live" version in the future before deploying it into production.  For more information, check out the "Road Map" section in this blog post:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160502104003/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4announcement.aspx)

As a final note, you should also know that because CTP's are meant as an early preview of new software, there are usually changes in the API that will occur before the final release.  This means that code you write against a CTP now can break when the final release is made.